# Qt copying extra files ino output/builddir

Tags: qt, build, qt-creator

The question is simple, I've even seen similar here, but still can't reach the desired result((

I wand to configure qt pro-file, so that additional resource files would be copied into the output, in msvs it's a matter of one checkbox, like "copy resource to the output", but currently Qt Creator is used, so i tried this in a pro-file:

```
DESTDIR = ../../../bin
CONFIG(debug, debug|release):DESTDIR = $$join(DESTDIR,,,_debug)

#copyfiles.commands = cp $$(TARGET)/user_accounts.sqlite $$(DESTDIR)/user_accounts.sqlite
copyfiles.commands = cp user_accounts.sqlite $$(DESTDIR)/user_accounts.sqlite

QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += copyfiles
POST_TARGETDEPS += copyfiles
```

cp is provided by msys, works ok from the command line. Still, when I build & run my project nothing happens. The recipe was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851471/including-resource-files-in-qt-creator-build-directory), not that i missed googling. Why so, could you help?

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solution:

```
win32 {
#convert to windows slash
PWD_WIN = $${PWD}
PWD_WIN ~= s,/,\\,g
OUT_PWD_WIN = $${OUT_PWD}
OUT_PWD_WIN ~= s,/,\\,g
#copy command      -> copy <from_project_dir> <to_build_dir>
copyfiles.commands = $(COPY_FILE) $${PWD_WIN}\\myFile.txt $${OUT_PWD_WIN}
}

QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += copyfiles
POST_TARGETDEPS += copyfiles
```